# Not sure why getting the last url for a redirect using CURL is working locally but not on production server

Tags: php, curl

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I have a URL that redirects to a media file. That is the information I am trying to retrieve. (The host and the path of the actual file).

Using this code

```
<?php 
$url='http://urs.pbs.org/redirect/71201be9214242cbbc32633826f8092b';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($ch);
$newurl=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$p = parse_url($newurl) ;
$rtmp=$p['scheme']."://".$p['host'];
$episode=$p['path'];
echo $rtmp.'<BR>';
echo $episode.'<BR>';
?>
```

Locally, it works fine.  But on my production server is just kicks back the $url.

It prints out 
http://urs.pbs.org
/redirect/71201be9214242cbbc3233826f8092b

Also, I should point out that **CURL is installed on the production server** and working fine.  I am not getting any errors.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you turn on verbose debugging? CURLOPT_DEBUG to true and you need to set CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION. Gives us that output or let us know that output solved it.

Comment: @motes Sorry, could you send me an example. I can't seem to find anything about CURLOPT_DEBUG at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php] (the php CURL page)

Comment: My fault, its [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl) set to true, and you dont **need** to set the CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION to a callback that will recieve the debug info, by default it will be sent to STDERR, our you can set CURLOPT_STDERR to a open file handle and the debug info will be saved there. I use cURL in C and always use a callback so I can see whats happening in libcURL in realtime by outputing to the debug window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` cannot be set `true` if safe mode is enabled, which is the case for many production environments. In this case tho a warning is triggered, something like this:

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx.php on line 56

My solution for this situation is manually following redirects for say 10 levels, making recursive curl requests.

**Update:**

Also `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` tells curl to return the result like this: `$result = curl_exec($ch);` so if you want it to print, put an `echo` before `curl_exec()`

Comment: Why wouldn't it being printing header, if it was onlt Location header causing the problem?

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` tells curl to return the result like this: `$result = curl_exec($ch);` so if you want it to print, put an `echo` before `curl_exec()`

Comment: @aorcsik Thanks for the tip. I realized I have warnings turned off -- so sure enough that's the issue. Thanks!